# Can I limit access to storage by subnet

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

With AWS, I can set a restriction to limit access to a bucket from specific IP addresses. This is important if you want to allow staff to access buckets from specific corporate systems ( or while connected via VPN ) while denying them from their personal systems. Can we do the same in Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IP filtering for **bucket access control** is currently not supported, however a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/63068776) has been submitted for this to be included and supported.